# How to let line numbers count from 1 in org subtree?

Tags: org-mode, doom, line-numbers

When I narrow an org mode header into a subtree(using command org-narrow-to-subtree) in vanilla Emacs, the line number counts from 1 in the subtree, but when I create a subtree in Doom Emacs, the line number counts from the original line number(e.g. if the header is on the 8000th line in the original file, the header in the subtree still starts from 8000, instead of 1). How can I make it count from 1 in the subtree?

[image]

Comment: What line numbering mode are you using?  display-line-numbers-mode (available since emacs 26) is both faster than older line-number modes (it's implemented in C not elisp I believe) and for me has the behaviour you say you want (i.e. when narrowed it counts from 1).

Comment: @CroadLangshan Thanks, but I believe I'm using `display-line-numbers-mode` because I've checked the value of `display-line-numbers-mode`, which is `t`. I also tried disabling the mode by running the `display-line-numbers-mode` command, the line numbers disappeared. Rerun the command redisplayed line numbers. So I think I'm using this mode to show line numbers.

Comment: What emacs version are you using?  I'm using 27.1, and the docs for variable `display-line-numbers` say "If the value is t, display the absolute number of each line of a buffer
shown in a window.  Absolute line numbers count from the beginning of
the current narrowing, or from buffer beginning.".  You might also poke around in variables starting with `display-line` (something like ivy or helm together with `C-h v` is helpful for that, or `M-x customize-group <RET> display-line-numbers` <RET>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in an appropriate place in your emacs configuration (not sure what file that is for doom):

```
(custom-set-variables
   '(display-line-numbers-widen nil))
```

I think you could use `setq-default` instead if you like, but I hear there are some subtleties that make `custom-set-variables` a better choice for customize-able variables -- it's OK to use `custom-set-variables` in your ordinary emacs config however you like -- just don't edit by hand the special customize call that is commented with `;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.` unless you know what you're doing.

Alternatively, you can use `M-x customize-variable <RET> display-line-numbers-widen <RET>`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! And as you said, only `customize-variable` worked. `setq` didn't work. Maybe `customize-variable` has higher priority.

Comment: Ah it automatically becomes buffer-local when set, so probably you'd have to use `setq-default` if you want to set a global default value across buffers (though since this is C-implemented, maybe it's even more special than that?  Haven't tested). Corrected my answer